# Use a previous input while asking for input to define a new variable

Tags: python, variables, input

```
userName = input("What is your name?")

firstInteger = (input ("Hi," , userName , "what is the first integer?"))
```

This just returns 
TypeError: input expected at most 1 arguments, got 3

I tried changing the userName to str(input(...)) and the userName in the firstInteger input to str(UserName), but neither working or changed the error message.

Comment: You use `+` to concatenate strings... not `,`. That's an argument separator

Comment: Or, make it easier on yourself. Use string formatting: `"Hi, {}, what is the first integer?".format(userName)`

Comment: You can use the comma in a print statement, but not string interpolation

Answer (score 0):

Here's the updated code based on the comments.

Also I'm not sure what version of python you're using, but older versions may require `raw_input` instead of `input`. If you're using Python 3.x, just `input` should work. Here's the updated code. Just replace `raw_input` with `input` if you are using Python 3.

```
userName = raw_input("What is your name?")

firstInteger = (raw_input ("Hi," + userName + " what is the first integer?"))
```